# Restoring CVS module from Attic

Tags: cvs

I have deleted one CVS module from repository i.e. HEAD. Now I need to restore the entire module from Attic to HEAD for project work.

Can you please explain with an example on how to restore deleted module from Attic to HEAD?

Answer (score 3):

@Burhan Ali is sort of correct. The reason there is no restore command is that CVS, like any version control system ( ok at the 30k foot level), represents a sequence of changes, or versions if you prefer, of a file. So if you want to restore from a remove, you have to create a fresh version with the contents. CVS stores removed files in the Attic directories, but you don't need to know that.

```
filename is example.c
last version before removal was 1.41
    cvs up -r 1.41 example.c
    mv example.c xxx
    cvs up -A example.c  ( resets to HEAD )
    mv xxx example.c
    cvs add example.c
    cvs ci
    cvs stat example.c
...
... revision 1.43  ( 1.42 was in the Attic, 1.43 == 1.41 )
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit command to restore something that has been deleted. You can check out an older version by date (`cvs checkout -D <date>`) and then use `cvs add` and `cvs commit` to add them back into CVS as the current version.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore the deleted file by first checking which revision the delete has (`cvs rlog`) and then deleting that revision with:

```
cvs admin -oREV filename
```

You can then do:

```
cvs co filename to get the revision before the delete.
```

You probably want to move the `filename,v` file from `Attic` in the repository to the parent directory, but this is not necessary in order to use the file.